# Cartoon show. A boy discovers a tablet in a library. Monsters emerge and fight

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

I can't remember the name of this show, but I remember the beginning.

A family of three (a mom, a kid and a wise old grampa) moved somewhere(?). I don't know where it was, but the kid wants to go explore then he ends up at a library(?). I think then he touched some kind of (red?) stone tablet, then a monster came out. The kid freaked out and ran away but then an enemy monster attacked then the kid's monster and the enemy monster fight.

The phrase "bob and weave" is commonly used during the first episode.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! These might help you to improve your question; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and [How to ask a good (anime) Story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-story-id-question/11875#11875)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this [Kaijudo: Rise of the Duel Masters](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Kaijudo:_Rise_of_the_Duel_Masters)?

The main character, [Ray](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Raiden_Pierce-Okamoto), lives with his [grandfather](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Raiden_Okamoto) and [mother](https://kaijudo.fandom.com/wiki/Janet_Pierce-Okamoto).

While it is not the first episode, here is a short clip from Hasbro entitled "Don't Say Bob and Weave!" where Ray's monster is fighting another monster in what looks like an underground library:

Answer (score 1):

Could this be [Huntik: Secrets & Seekers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huntik:_Secrets_%26_Seekers)?

> The series follows Lok Lambert as he uncovers the secret legacy of his
>   missing father. His father, Eathon, was a member of the Huntik
>   Foundation and a part of a secret world of magic users known as
>   Seekers and creatures known as Titans. On his mission to uncover what
>   happened to his father, Lok is joined by Dante Vale, Sophie
>   Casterwill, Zhalia Moon, and a talking Titan called Cherit. Season
>   one focuses on the fight against the evil Organization, led by a
>   powerful Seeker known as the Professor. Along the way, the team
>   discovers the Amulet of Will and the powerful Legendary Titans. Though
>   the Professor eventually acquires the three Legendary Titans of Mind,
>   Body, and Spirit in a bid for immortality, he is defeated by the
>   Huntik team.

[image]

Comment: No mom, no grandpa, no tablet, the journal (and amulet, but not a tablet IIRC) is discovered by breaking a vase, not being in a library... Really apart from the "there are monsters" bit, I don't think it's a match so far.

Comment: @Jenayah - I recall that his grandfather told him to bob and weave to deal with bullies.

Comment: @Jenayah - A very similar description of the show here; https://www.reddit.com/r/HelpMeFind/comments/d3tpf1/help_me_remember_this_show/ - "*one day, he finds a ring and when he looks threw it he sees a whole nother world with monster and all types of mystic creatures...basically explain to the kid that he is like the chosen one or something to capture and tame monster s and junk. If this helps her also had a grandpa who told him to bob and weave if the bullies started bullying him idk why I remembered that but yea*"

Comment: All things considered and having skimmed through the first episode again, I still don't think that's enough of a match. (No offense whatsoever, just didn't want to blank you)